# Context visual counter size

Tags: context, visualcounter

I want to reduce the text size and also the visual counter size for context presentation. I have the following options setup

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\definevisualcounter
    [userpage]
    [countdown]
    [
      style=\tfxx,
      counter=userpage,
      palette=counter,
]
```

What is the way to reduce the font size to some thing less than xx?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `style={\switchtobodyfont[5pt]}`

Answer (score 3):

ConTeXt does not define any relative font size smaller than `xx`. Although you can define new relative font size switches; if you need a smaller fontsize just for visual counter, you can use `style={\switchtobodyfont[5pt]}` to scale to absolute font size.